# Google Identity: Client error POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token Response Invalid grant Bad request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, postman

I used Postman to test the request to Google Identity API.

I followed the [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code) of Google Identity, I succeeded for the 4 first steps of "Obtaining OAuth 2.0 access tokens" but for the last step I followed exactly the doc but for that step I get the following 400 error:

[image]

What's is wrong with my request, could you please help?

Comment: Why are you including the **code** as a POST query parameter?

Comment: @John Hanley, did you read the doc? To exchange the code to access token and refresh token, the doc states that we need to use a POST request.

Comment: If you read the docs, including the one you reference, you will see that the code and several other params are form encoded in the POST body. That is why I asked about your usage of a query parameter.